# How to plot camera positon in the world coordinate system?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, camera-calibration

I've calculated the camera position and got the object feature points in the 3D world coordinate system.
I want to plot them like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmOnZ.png), but in my example, it's not a stereo camera.

I feel like I have to use Matplotlib but I'm not that familiar with it, so I don't know what to look for. How can I do this?

Comment: Is there some code you've been working on? Have you looked at the matplotlib example gallery yet?

Comment: @PaulH I looked at the matplotlib example gallery, I didn't know there was such a thing. I guess I have to use markers for the object points and linestyles to draw the camera. But I still don't know to go about doing that. Regarding my code, I'm trying to calibrate the camera and find the camera position. I've found the camera position but I'm now stuck at how to plot it

Comment: no one can help you w/o seeing what you've done and explicitly stating what the problem is